# Set ReadOnly Property from collection class

Tags: c#

It is little hard to explain what I want, but basically, I want to set a ReadOnly property from a collection class. I know it is not that simple.

```
public class ListItemCollection : CollectionBase {
      // other code

      public void Add(ListItem item) {
            item.Index = List.Count;  // want to set Index
            List.Add(item);
      }
}
```

I don't want other class from ListItemCollection to change the value of that property.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
     private void Form_Load(....) {
          ListItem item = new ListItem;
          item.Index = 5; // I don't want people to set it.
     }

}
```

I know that it is possible somehow because `ListViewItem` manage to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it if you place `ListItem` in the same assembly as `ListItemCollection`, and give the `Index` property a public getter and an internal setter:

```
class ListItem {
    // other code
    public int Index {get; internal set;}
}
```

Technically, it wouldn't make the property `readonly`, but as far as the other users of the `ListItem` class are concerned, the property would appear to have no setter.

If `ListItem` must be in a different assembly, you could let the `ListItemCollection` class see the setter by using the [`InternalsVisibleTo` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for detail information. I will try `internal` since they are in the same assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) for the `set`. This makes it accessible from classes in the same assembly, but not from outside it.

```
public int Index { get; internal set; }
```

Comment: +1 for answer. I will try `internal`. Thanks for your quick answer.